# Strange behavior of class property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I declare `a` as class property of Foo, which will be a property of all instances of Foo.

Behavior is different when value of `a` gets from literal or another variable.

Why?

```js
{
   class Foo {
    a = {a: 3}
   }

   const f1 = new Foo()
   const f2 = new Foo()
   console.log(f1.a)
   console.log(f2.a)
   f1.a.a = 4
   console.log(f1.a) // {a: 4}
   console.log(f2.a) // {a: 3}
}
 
{ 
   const outer = {a: 3}

   class Foo {
    a = outer
   }

   const f1 = new Foo()
   const f2 = new Foo()
   console.log(f1.a)
   console.log(f2.a)
   f1.a.a = 4
   console.log(f1.a)  // {a: 4}
   console.log(f2.a)  // {a: 4}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because `a = outer` does not make a copy and all class instances share reference to same outer object.

The first example creates a new object in constructor every time a `new` instance is created

If you did `a = {...outer}` each instance would be a shallow copy and your examples would work the same

Comment: Oh, I got it. Property a declaration will be executed every time a new instance is created, it is not executed once in the process of class declaration, this is the key. I knew assignment in JS is just name binding.

Comment: Exactly ...because of `new` each is individual instance

Comment: I think assignment is not key, at least for me, do you want to edit your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Edit with what exactly?

Comment: Firstly, property a declaration is executed every time a new instance is created. Secondly  about assignment.

Answer (score 0):

JS objects are passed by reference.

So when you do `a = outer` you put in `a` the **reference** of `outer`. That's why `a` changes whenever `outer` changes (and vise versa).

If you want your code to recreate the `outer` object, use `a = Object.create(outer)`

Here is an example:

```js
let a = {
  foo: "hi im a"
};
console.log(a);
let b = a;
b.foo = "hi im b";
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

let c = Object.create(a);
c.foo = "hi im c";
console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, it's due to reference being passed. Instead of explaining using your example, I'll try using another example, using object

```js
const personA = { name: 'Isaac' };
const personB = personA;
personB.name = 'John';

console.log(personA)
```

If you realized, `personA.name` has becoming `John`, eventhou we only updating `personB.name`, this is `object passed by reference` in action

And to avoid this behaviour, you can use spread operator.

```js
const personA = { name: 'Isaac' };
const personB = {...personA};
personB.name = 'John';

console.log(personA)
```